# Convert file .pptx to .ppt using Java

Tags: java, powerpoint

I was wondering if someone knows a way to convert .pptx to .ppt progamatically using Java?

Comment: Please use comments to ask for clarification on an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use openoffice for conversion. You have to configure eclipse/netbeans [properly](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/FirstSteps/Configuration). You need jodconverter plugin, too.
oh, and remember to open OO in [listening mode](http://www.artofsolving.com/node/10)

```
package openofficeconv;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.ConnectException;

import com.artofsolving.jodconverter.DocumentConverter;
import com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.connection.*;
import com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.converter.OpenOfficeDocumentConverter;

public class PowerpointConverter{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    File inputFile = new File("j.pptx");
    File outputFile = new File("j.pdf");

    // connect to an OpenOffice.org instance running on port 8100
    OpenOfficeConnection connection = new SocketOpenOfficeConnection(8100);
    try {
        connection.connect();
    } catch (ConnectException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // convert
    DocumentConverter converter = new OpenOfficeDocumentConverter(connection);
    converter.convert(inputFile, outputFile);

    // close the connection
    connection.disconnect();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Aspose Slides](http://www.aspose.com/categories/java-components/aspose.slides-for-java/default.aspx) is the only library I've seen that understands pptx. It's not free but it would probably have the ability to do the conversion. Apache POI is a free ppt Java library but last I checked it didn't support pptx.

Update: here's how I extracted images using Aspose. Once you have png files, you should be able to build a PDF using other tools. I needed explicitly sized images - you may be able to just get it as the native size:

```
Dimension small = new Dimension(160, 120);
Dimension medium = new Dimension(200,150);
Dimension large = new Dimension(400,300);

for (Slide slide : presentation.getSlides()) {
  String path = FileService.getUploadPath() + slide.getPath();
  com.aspose.slides.Slide pptSlide = ppt.getSlideByPosition(slide.getSequence());
  ImageIO.write(pptSlide.getThumbnail(1, 1), "png", new File(path));

  path = FileService.getUploadPath() + slide.getSmallPath();
  ImageIO.write(pptSlide.getThumbnail(small), "png", new File(path));

  path = FileService.getUploadPath() + slide.getMediumPath();
  ImageIO.write(pptSlide.getThumbnail(medium), "png", new File(path));

  path = FileService.getUploadPath() + slide.getLargePath();
  ImageIO.write(pptSlide.getThumbnail(large), "png", new File(path));
}
```

Comment: POI supports PPTX through POI-OpenXML4J. I haven't used it, but Aspose looks solid as well,

Comment: Ok, I was looking at this line from the POI link: HSLF is the POI Project's pure Java implementation of the Powerpoint '97(-2007) file format. It does not support the new PowerPoint 2007 .pptx file format, which is not OLE2 based.

Comment: I tried with Aspose Slide, and I have some problems with it. It does the convertion from .pptx to pdf, and on the pdf, I have no images. My aim is to convert .pptx to pdf. I have a solution that convert .ppt to pdf.

Comment: Updated with example of how to get images.

Comment: Thanks, now I have the picture using Aspose.

But I have another issue still with picture. On another presentation, I crop the picture using PowerPointOffice. When I generate the pdf file, the picture is full size.
Someone know how I can get the good size, the one that I crop?

Comment: Have you tried the latest version of [Aspose.Slides for Java](http://www.aspose.com/community/files/72/java-components/aspose.slides-for-java/default.aspx)? If not, please download and try at your end. If you still find the same issue or it doesn't completely satisfy your requirement then please post a query in [Aspose.Slides support](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.slides-product-family/109/showforum.aspx) forum so our support/development team would be able to suggest a solution or add new feature to cater your scenario. Disclosure: I work as a developer evangelist at Aspose.