# can i use docx4j concept for pptx to image fileconversion in java and Docx4j

Tags: java, powerpoint, docx4j

I'm try to convert pptx into image files in java, but i couldn't achieve yet. but i found docx4j    http://dev.plutext.org/svn/docx4j/trunk/docx4j/docs/Docx4j_GettingStarted.pdf and http://dev.plutext.org/blog/category/microsoft-word/, but i can't configure that.. anybody hav the experience of using Docx4j.. share your thoughts.. thanks in advance.

Comment: Try the docx4j/pptx4j forums.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps taking the extra step of transforming the ppt(x) into a pdf and then creating images out of the pdf is an option. I'm positively sure you can find libraries to do that last part.

Another suggestion would be to save the pptx as ppt and have [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/slideshow/how-to-shapes.html#Render) convert the slides into images.

Cheers,
Wim

Comment: Hi wivani , thanks for your response , i can convert ppt to image ,  but i couldn't find that suitable pptx file handle poi jar see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206002/convert-file-pptx-to-ppt-using-java , so onely i try to doc4x but it makes me lot of confuse of setting the doc4x environment